# gcc found but not executing on windows git bash

Tags: windows, bash, gcc, msys

I installed gcc on windows via msys32. On powershell and on command prompt it executes properly.

The only strange thing: `which gcc` yields `/usr/bin/gcc`, yes with unix slashes. 
In real world it is installed in `~/AppData/Roaming/msys32/usr/bin` so the msys path is cut off.

In git bash gcc yields no `command not found` but just nothing. 
Also `which gcc` yields `/c/Users/ere/AppData/Roaming/msys32/usr/bin/gcc`.

So the problem is specific for git bash, right? But I cannot interpret the outcome.

Any ideas?

Comment: `which gcc` yielding `/usr/bin/gcc` is the correct behaviour.

Comment: Does `gcc --version` give output?

Comment: In MSYS shell type `moint` to see which paths are translated to what exactly. Also `~` refers to the folder pointed to by the `HOME` environment variable (type `echo $HOME` in MSYS shell to see its value).